# How to Deserialise Xml into a Dictionary<int,string> object?

Tags: c#, xml, dictionary, serialization, generics

Is it possible to Deserialize the following piece of XML into a `Dictionary<int,string>` object?

XML:

```
<Config>

<DatabaseConnections>
     <Connection Name="Source Connection" Value="ConnectionStringValue" />
     <Connection Name="Target Connection" Value="ConnectionStringValue" />
<DatabaseConnections>

<Config>
```

I have a class which will have a property of `Dictionary<int,string> {get;set;}`

I would like to use the following C# code to do this:

```
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Config));

using(StringReader sr = new StringReader(rootnode.OuterXml))
{
      return (Config)xs.Deserialize(sr);
}
```

Are there any alternatives to doing this?

Comment: why it is Dictionary<int,string> ?? Shouldnt it be Dictionary<string,string> or how you want to map string to int and what goes in value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use the default `XmlSerializer` implementation to (de)serialize `IDictionary` objects to Xml. From the MSDN [`XmlSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) documentation:

> The XmlSerializer gives special
>   treatment to classes that implement
>   IEnumerable or ICollection. A class
>   that implements IEnumerable must
>   implement a public Add method that
>   takes a single parameter. The Add
>   method's parameter must be of the same
>   type as is returned from the Current
>   property on the value returned from
>   GetEnumerator, or one of that type's
>   bases.

The `Dictionary<>` class implements both interfaces, but does not have an `Add` method that takes a single parameter, so it fails.

More to the point, the xml serialization code explicitly disallows classes that implement `IDictionary` (from Reflector, looking at `TypeScope.GetDefaultIndexer`):

```
 if (typeof(IDictionary).IsAssignableFrom(type)) {
        if (memberInfo == null) {
            throw new NotSupportedException(...);
        }
        throw new NotSupportedException(...);
 }
```

So you can't even make the work by subclassing `Dictionary<>` and adding the required `Add` overload.

The article [Generic Dictionaries vs. the XmlSerializer](http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2006/07/09/generic-dictionaries-vs-the-xmlserializer/) describes one workaround:

> 1. First, decorate the Dictionary property with
>      an XmlIgnore attribute. This tells the
>      XmlSerializer to ignore that property,
>      eliminating the reflection error.
> 2. Create a new public property that takes and returns an array of
>      DictionaryEntry objects. I tend to
>      name these specially
>      (_x_DictionaryName) so that it is
>      clear one should not generally use
>      this property.
> 3. Serialize away.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this class: [SerializableDictionary](http://weblogs.asp.net/pwelter34/archive/2006/05/03/444961.aspx).

You will need to change the property type, of course:

```
public class Config
{
     public SerializableDictionary<String, String> DatabaseConnections
     { get; set; }
}
```